# Django filter datetime with timezone field with date only

Tags: python, django

I have a field in django model: "created_at" which is datetime with timezone (example: 2022-08-09 14:03:18.467482+02). In my app, I have a form where user selects date only (example: 2022-06-09).

I'm trying to filter that field in my view like this:

```
res = MyObject.objects.all()
res = res.filter(created_at = date)
```

I'm getting the following error: `RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Mybject.created_at received a naive datetime (2022-06-09 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.`

What is the best way to to filter my object with user input date? Do I need to add timezone to user selected date and how?

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve this, the correct syntax is adding double underscore like this:

```
res = res.filter(created_at__date = date)
```

Answer (score -2):

Datetime has the attributes `created_at.date` and `created_at.time`

```
res = MyObject.objects.filter(created_at__date=date)
```

Comment: This breaks the code with the following error ```SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?```. If i change it to == , I get ```NameError: name 'created_at' is not defined```